# I want to connect with my: online MySQL database, but I get this error. Can someone help me?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to make connection to my online database, but then I get this error:

> Warning: mysqli :: mysqli (): ( HY000 / 2002 ): A connection attempt failed because the " Related party Incorrectly If the answer after a certain time , of the costs Connection failed because " the Confederate host has not responded . C: \ wamp \ www \ array Add in db \ 222.php on line 8

This is my code:

```
?php

$servername = "db.tapdeleest.nl"; $username = "***"; $password = "***"; $dbname = "***";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
else
{
echo "nice";
}

?>
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant php.

Comment: Could you remove the dislike, please?

Comment: Are you connecting remotely? If so, check if remote connections are enabled.

Comment: No, you don't have them enabled, or no you aren't connecting remotely?

Comment: Not connecting remotely

Comment: If you are not connecting remotely then `$servername` should be localhost no?

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question, this is an online database, so I think I'm connecting remotely.

Comment: Database is online and your php files are also on same host right? If yes then `$servername` should be localhost. If not, you need to enable remote connections to database.

Comment: What do you mean with: "php files are also on same host"? This is the database of my friend and he told me to use this code.

Comment: Then he needs to set remote connection access for you.

Comment: Thanks, I will ask him!

Answer (score 0):

Using new mysqli() you don't add the database name in your connection.

You use mysqli_select_db($conn, $dbname)

```
<?php

$servername = "db.tapdeleest.nl"; $username = "***"; $password = "***"; $dbname = "***";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
else
{
   echo "nice";
   mysqli_select_db($conn, $dbname);
}

?>
```

Just advice: Give pdo a try, I feel like pdo is easier.
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

Comment: It's not working either and it doesn't care if you type your: dbname into: $conn.